# How to decode NSString UTF-8

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I am using `SBJSONParser` to parse a `JSON` from an API. I am getting the following `title = "F\U00c3\U00b6rdermittel";` and it is already UTF-8 encoded from `SBJSONParser`.
The string should be 'Fördermittel' but I am getting `FÃ¶rdermittel`.
I am calling `[dict objectForKey:@"title"];` to get the string.

All I found by googlin' is `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)]` but I am having a `NSString` object non an `char`

Comment: If you are deploying for iOS5 I recommend to use the build in JSON parser.

Comment: That helped, please add it as an answer, so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: The damage was done when the data was received.  It should have been immediately converted to NSString, using the correct character encoding, before feeding to the JSON parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are deploying for iOS5 I recommend to use the build in JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no method in the NSString API to decode a UTF-8 NSString directly, so first it has to be converted to a C string

```
NSString *encodedString;
NSString *decodedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[encodedString cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
```

Comment: That didn't helped me, I uses `NSJSONSerialization` as suggested by @dasdom .

Comment: This is actually a good try, but the C string needs to be a pure extraction of the low-order bytes.  Unfortunately, I don't see a way to do that other than to iterate through the characters.